# Bypass Google's "Personalization settings & cookies" (consent.google.com) page, setting everything to off

Tags: web-browser, firefox, privacy, cookies, google

Google recently introduced the "Personalization settings & cookies" page when you visit it for the "first" time, e.g. when you browse to https://www.google.com/ you get

[image]

and if you click "Customise" you are redirected to https://consent.google.com/d?continue=https://www.google.com/ where you have to manually click "Off" for every option, while allowing all cookies is (of course!) just one click.

It only pops up once - if you allow cookies. However, I don't want to allow cookies from Google and I don't want to accept any more of their "improvements" than I absolutely must to use the service, which means that I have to go through this every time I want to use some Google service.

Is there a browser extension (preferably for Firefox) or Greasemonkey script or similar that will automate clicking "Customise" and then clicking "Off" for everything on the following page for me?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the Firefox extension "[I don't care about cookies](https://www.i-dont-care-about-cookies.eu/)". It definitely makes the prompt go away, but I'm not sure if it actually accepts or rejects the cookies. On my system I don't get any cookies by using Google, but I'm also using a VPN with NetShield and the strict cookie policy in Firefox, so might be either of those that does the magic.

Comment: Thanks, that does make the prompt go away (I have to allow it in Incognito mode). It probably just accepts the cookies, though, which is not ideal.